# how to replace new parameters on Jquery string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace only one parameter or fast with Jquery on Jquery String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142637/how-to-replace-only-one-parameter-or-fast-with-jquery-on-jquery-string)

The site have the query string is:

```
http://www.nonloso.html/?nome1=pollo&cognome1=chicken&nome2=a&cognome2=b&nome3=c&cognome3=d
```

This is the site where I have sent three form but now I would like to change the name of the second form that I sent. **(nome=a&cognome=b)**
Unless the data with the procedure that I read the site and subject to the variable.
I edit the field (variable) but as I'm going to rewrite on the site.
From name=a and surname=b that the site would become the new parameters.

```
http://www.nonloso.html/?nome1=pollo&cognome1=chicken&nome2=565655&cognome2=8765634&nome3=c&cognome3=d.
```

HoW???
How do I edit the site by changing only the values ​​of interest?

I repeat:
Before the my site is

```
http://www.nonloso.html/?nome1=pollo&cognome1=chicken&nome2=a&cognome2=b&nome3=c&cognome3=d
```

After with the script Javascrits or Jquery or ajax (is possible??) is

```
http://www.nonloso.html/?nome1=pollo&cognome1=chicken&nome2=565655&cognome2=8765634&nome3=c&cognome3=d
```

**There is one solution or example**?

Comment: Is this ajax or not? If not, do you want to change it on the page that has the bad query string?

Comment: this duplicate is my... because this question is recent for the people

Comment: Are `565655` and `8765634` random numbers? Or where do they come from?

Comment: This come from two textarea or variable of javascript...

Comment: I want to know how to replace the relevant value... always please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
var change={
    nome2:565655,
    cognome2:8765634
}
if(window.location.search){
    var que = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),
        newArr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<que.length;i++){
        var qvar = que[i].split("=");
        if(change[qvar[0]]){
            qvar[1]=change[qvar[0]];
        }
        newArr.push(qvar.join('='));
    }
    window.location.search="?"+newArr.join('&');
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, the code above works but it's an eternal loop. Then, use

```
var change={
    nome2:565655,
    cognome2:8765634
}
if(window.location.search){
    var que = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),
        newArr=[],
        changeURL=false;
    for(var i=0;i<que.length;i++){
        var qvar = que[i].split("=");
        if(change[qvar[0]]&&change[qvar[0]]!=qvar[1]){
            console.log('URL changed because of '+change[qvar[0]]+' != '+qvar[1]);
            qvar[1]=change[qvar[0]];
            changeURL=true;
        }
        newArr.push(qvar.join('='));
    }
    if(changeURL){
        window.location.search="?"+newArr.join('&');
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's plain JavaScript. But jQuery (the library itself, not the code that you use when you use the library) is plain JavaScript too.